# Optimization accumulation of vectors for monte carlo simulation

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, montecarlo

I want to optimize the following code:

During a monte carlo simulation I accumulate some quantities `f(x)` (`f(x)` is expensive to compute) and save them in the array `bins` after every sampling step.

EDIT: f(x) is not a deterministic function of x (by that i mean it generates pseudo random numbers and uses them to modify the result) and also depends on previoulsy calculated values f(y)

```
for(int n=0;n<N;n++)
{
    // compute some values f(x) at points "p"
    for(auto k: p) bins[k] += f(k);
}
```

`p.size()` is much smaller than the size of `bins`, but eventually most elements will be set.

After the simulation I accumulate my final values by doing a weighted sum over `bins` (`g` is a lookup in another array):

```
for(int l=0;l<M;l++)
    for(int k=0;k<bins.size();k++)
        finalResult[l] += g(k,l)*bins[k];
```

I could of course compute my updated `finalResult` after every sampling step, this does however slow the program down a lot, due to the loop over `M`.

I already tried a very basic `boost::accumulate`, but this did not improve performance (if I stay with this design I will have to use it eventually due to stability, though).

All arrays are of type `Eigen::MatrixXd` since I need them for BLAS operations.

> ```
> p.size() < 10^2
> N ~ 10^7
> M ~ 10^4
> bins.size() ~ 10^5
> ```

Do you have any suggestions on which techniques could be useful for optimization here?

Comment: The method you're using looks fairly well optimized already. Is there some reason why you expect that it could be improved? I would generally expect that, assuming you're not doing anything really silly like needlessly computing the same expensive value twice in a row, any significant improvements would have to come from high-level changes to the Monte Carlo simulation algorithm.

Comment: the monte carlo algorithm is already highly optimized (there are a lot of matrix/vector products which cannot be furtehr reduced). profiling he application seemed to suggest, that this accumulation takes up the most time. so my hope was that i overlooked some less obvious optimization

Answer (score 1):

Try computing `f(x)` just once for each of the `N` values (i.e. memoization). So for instance, if `N` is large (like it is in this situation), try changing your loop to something like the following:

```
static std::unordered_map<unsigned int, double> memoizedFunction;
for(int n=0;n<N;n++)
{
    // compute some values f(x) at points "p"
    for(auto k: p) 
    {
        auto it = memoizedFunction.find( k );
        if (it == memoizedFunction.end())
        {
             it = memoizedFunction.emplace( f(k) ).first;
        }

        bins[k] += *it;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could just store the number of times the `k`th bin has been `hit` in `bins[k]` and then at the end go through and compute `bins[k] * f(k)` for each `k`.

Comment: better that a find/emplace, an insert/set should improve perf!

Comment: this is actually a very good idea, i have already thought about that with regards to g. f(x) however has a random component since it comes from a monte carlo simulation (i really should have said that in the explanation above). this also means, f(k+1) depends on f(k) in a non obvious way.

Answer (score 0):

> Just a thought here but you if you could verify that f(x) is a linear
>   transformation then you could create the matrix *A* such that
>
> ```
> [f(x)] = A[x] where [x] is the coordinates of x with respect to some basis B.
> ```
>
> That could make f(x) easier and faster to compute especially if x
>   exists in a vector space with a small basis.
>
> However if converting between coordinates and the answer is expensive
>   that could overall kill any benefits (just keep that in mind).
>
> Here are some links that could help explain matrix representation of
>   linear transformations.
>
> https://math.colorado.edu/~nita/MatrixRepresentations.pdf
>   https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m24w07/public_html/Lecture12.pdf
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix